# Is it possible for string.index() to have negative number?

Tags: python, string

I was looking at a solution to a question at geeksforgeeks and I stumbled upon the function `index()` and `rindex()`.

Below is part of the code and I was wondering whether the code has an error. Is it possible for `index()` and `rindex()` to even be -1? If the string does not contain the substring, doesn't it return an error?

```
# find index of last occurrence of 
# character x in the input string 
last = string.rindex(x) 

# find index of first occurrence of 
# character y in the input string 
first = string.index(y) 

# return false if x or y are not present 
# in the input string OR last occurrence of 
# x is after the first occurrence of y 
# in the input string 
if last == -1 or first == -1 or last > first:
    return False
```

Comment: The person who wrote this got it mixed up with [`find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find).

Comment: `index()` and `rindex()` will throw ValueError exceprtion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippet you shared seems to be wrong. [`index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) will indeed raise a `ValueError` if the substring isn't found (unlike [`find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) that will return -1).

Comment: Can I conclude that maybe instead of using `index` and `rindex`, the user should have used `find` and `rfind`?

Comment: @JohnTho We can't read the author's mind, but it does seem that their intent was to use `find`/`rfind`, not `index`/`rindex`.

Answer (score 1):

string.index returns `ValueError` when it did not find the substring.

string.find returns -1 when it did not find the substring.

refer to [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) link